# Estimating variance of Poisson Binomial random variable

Tags: estimation, binomial-distribution, beta-binomial-distribution, poisson-binomial-distribution

Let's say I have a weighted coin, with probability $p_i$ of being heads. I flip $N_i$ times, and estimate $P_i$ and the variance on $p_i$ using the relevant formulas for a Binomial distribution. Call this estimated mean and variance $\hat{p}_i$ and $\hat{\sigma}_i$.

Now I repeat this same process $M$ times, and I know that every time I repeat it, the $p_i$ will change, though I don't know the distribution from which it is drawn. My goal is to estimate the mean of the $p_i$, which I'll call $\hat{P}$, and it's sample variance, $\hat{\sigma}_P$.

I know that this process is related to a [Poisson Binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution), which describes he total number of heads I will find over the entire $M\times N$ trials. However, I'm not sure how to estimate the $\hat{P}$ and $\hat{\sigma}_P$, and how these are related to the Poisson-Binomial values.